# Animate the images while scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I am using animate.css from http://daneden.me/animate

I want to animate the images while scrolling down and when the image gets focused. I am adding the class .animated in  tag and the type of animation in data-animate attribute like the below:

HTML

```
<img src="images/img-grow.png" alt="Grow" class="img-responsive animated" data-animate="bounceInRight">
```

When the image gets focused during scroll down it should add data-animate attribute i.e bounceInRight to the class so that that animation will take place.

It can be bounceInRight or bounceInLeft or any other animation tag as in animate.css

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  if ($(".animated").focus() ) {
      var elementAnimation = $(this).attr('data-animate');
       $(this).addClass( elementAnimation );
   }
});
```

But above code is not working. Any help?

Also it is better to have the animation take place once only per page refresh.

Comment: Just use `wow.js` combine with `animate.css`

Comment: It costs $99 for license

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var animateHeight = $(".img-responsive").offset().top;

$(function() {
    var addAnimation = $('.img-responsive');
    var animateHeight = $(".img-responsive").offset().top;
    var animateHeight_end  = $(".img-responsive").offset().top + $(".img-responsive").height();
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (scroll >= animateHeight && scroll <=  animateHeight_end ) {
            addAnimation.addClass('animated bounceInRight');
        } else {
            addAnimation.removeClass('animated bounceInRight');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It should add class capturing from data-animate attribute.